Female journalist hides a death row inmate
This movie was set somewhere in the 80s/90s and was about a newspaper/journalist woman who interviews a man who is going on death row except he is innocent. The execution was the electric chair and the lights go out and he escapes and the woman helps hide him. The death row inmate was an old man and one actor I remember was Tom Selleck or someone who look liked him. The woman hides him at her office (the newspaper hq) and SWAT comes in hunting him. It is a comedy and in the end, the mayor let him off.

I think you mean Switching Channels (1988) with Kathleen Turner, Burt Reynolds & Christopher Reeve:

Sully is the producer of a cable news network program. Christy is his ex-wife and best reporter. Her desire to quit the news business and marry Blaine, a sporting goods manufacturer comes as an innocent man is about to be executed. Sully's attempts to keep her in town and break up her upcoming marriage happen against the backdrop of a botched execution, a prison break and a possible pardon. 

It was a loose adaptation of His Girl Friday, which has a similar plot. Here's the trailer:




That is the movie.
